# Error java.lang.NullPointerException on a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

I been trying to figure out why this line

`myArr[line][i] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[i]);`

doesn't work and i get this error `java.lang.NullPointerException`

What I'm trying to do here is to read lines of a .txt file with the `BufferedReader` that looks like this and then split it them and putting it on a double array called `myArr`

`1,500,600
2,300,800
3,800,1000
4,200,5000`

`

```
   private static int[][] myArr;
   BufferedReader br = null;    

   BufferedReader br2 = null;   

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Ifrahim\\Desktop\\Procesos.txt"));
        //br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Ifrahim\\Desktop\\Procesos.txt"));

        //int lines = (int) br2.lines().count();
         //myArr = new int[lines][3];

        int line = 0;
        while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
             String[] tmp = sCurrentLine.split(",");//split the line up into its separate values

             for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
                  myArr[line][i] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[i]);
                  //convert the values into integers and insert them at the matching position
                  //in the array


             line++;
        }

         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArr));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Where are you declaring and initializing `myArr`? Are those two commented-out lines where you declare  `lines` and initialize `myArr` actually commented out when you run it?

Comment: i edited it is private static int[][] myArr;

Comment: You still need to initialise the array, static or not.

Answer (score 3):

Uncomment this:

```
//myArr = new int[lines][3];
```

You're not initializing the array, so it's null when you try to populate it.